# sql stored procedure argument as parameter for dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

This procedure has three parameters. But when I try to execute by passing parameters it shows me an error. Please help me.

```
create procedure queryfunctions @Tabname varchar(150),@colname varchar(150),@valuesname varchar(150)
as
begin
declare @sql varchar(4000)
select @sql='select * from @Tabname where @colname=@valuesname'
exec(@sql)
end

exec queryfunctions 'education','eduChildName','Revathi'
```

**Error :**

> Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>           Must declare the table variable "@Tabname".

Comment: Can you please confirm that you are looking for the row(s) in the `education` table where the `eduChildName` column contains the string value `'Revathi'` and not the row(s) where the `eduChildName` column contains the same value as the `Revathi` column?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it was pulling too much downvotes for some reason. Sorry baji, you are on your own with the other answers that you got, even if they are not so helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a much safer alternative:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.queryfunctions 
  @Tabname NVARCHAR(511),
  @colname NVARCHAR(128),
  @valuesname VARCHAR(150)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @Tabname 
           + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@colname) + ' = @v';

  EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@v VARCHAR(150)', @valuesname;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.queryfunctions N'dbo.education', N'eduChildName', 'Revathi';
```

What did I change?

1. Always use `dbo` prefix when creating / referencing objects.
2. Table and column names are `NVARCHAR` and *can* be longer than 150 characters. Much safer to allow the parameters to accommodate a table someone might add in the future.
3. Added `SET NOCOUNT ON` as a guard against network overhead and potentially sending erroneous result sets to client.
4. `@sql` should always be `NVARCHAR`.
5. Use `QUOTENAME` around entity names such as tables or columns to help thwart SQL injection and also to guard against poorly chosen names (e.g. keywords).
6. Use proper parameters where possible (again to help thwart SQL injection but also to avoid having to do all kinds of escaping of delimiters on string parameters).

Comment: Aaron, I am sure Quotename will work 100% unless there are object names with more than 128 characters (Which is rare to have). I just want to point out this :)

Comment: @Madhivanan please let me know how you can create an object with a name > 128 characters (I get an error). `QUOTENAME` was written explicitly to deal with object names and the understanding that an identifier cannot exceed 128 characters.

Comment: You are right.I misunderstood that. I have seen people using Quotename in dynamic sql over not only on object names but on values too to put single quotes around it. Like Quotename(@v,''''). When I posted I kept that in mind but wrongly specified the object names

Comment: -1 You are assuming things about the question, and downvoting other answers because don't ASSUME THE SAME THING.

Comment: Prefixing objects with `dbo` is a good idea, as is using `QUOTENAME` for delimiting names. But if you are applying `QUOTENAME` to a parameter like that, you shouldn't pass the name with a prefix, or [you'll end up with a wrong object name](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4551).

Comment: @AndriyM of course, good point. I wrote the procedure itself based on the sample call in the question, then added the EXEC call based on my bullets.

Answer (score -3):

Why are you passing object names as parameters?

If you pass string value to @valuesname, your code should be

```
create procedure queryfunctions 
(
@Tabname varchar(150),@colname varchar(150),@valuesname varchar(150) 
)
as 
begin 
declare @sql varchar(4000) 
select @sql='select * from '+@Tabname+' where '+@colname+'='''+@valuesname+'''' 
exec(@sql) 
end
```

Don't know how to use single quotes in dynamic sql? Refer this http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10827/understanding-single-quotes.aspx